# Excel 2013 vba - Refresh Pivot Tables - Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have some vb code that will refresh my pivot tables for me, is there a way to loop this so I can refresh pivot tables 1 to 20 say? Rather than listing 20 lines of code below Eg

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(2).PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables(3).PivotCache.Refresh
```

Etc..

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example: If you want to refresh all pivot caches in your workbook, you can do something like this:

```
Sub RefreshPivotCache()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<~~ Loop all worksheets in workbook
        For Each PT In ws.PivotTables        '<~~ Loop all pivot tables in worksheet
            PT.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next PT
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, this will also go through each worksheet in the workbook, and each pivot table in each sheet and refresh & update the table.

```
Sub RefreshPivotData()
Dim pvotCht As PivotTable, Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pvotTbl In Sheet.PivotTables
            pvotTbl.RefreshTable
            pvotTbl.Update
        Next
    Next
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Option Explicit

```
Sub RefresfPivotTables()

Sheets("YOUR_SHEET").Select

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 20

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & i).PivotCache.Refresh

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i'm thinking this is the best solution so I can spec the number of pivots. However sometimes the pivot is connected to a read only file, The read only file is open and I can refresh outside of vb but when I try to run from vb I get a 1004 error. Is there anything I can add to handle this? Many thanks in advance!